# How to access a file Tags data from file metadata collection in windows,C#

Tags: c#, taglib

If we select a file in windows and go to its properties and in tab detail we have some metadata information related to that file. how to access those information using c# .net?
i saw people are referencing using id3,taglib these third party libraries returns some parts of metadata. what i need is the "Tags" row data as shown in bellow image link.
 https://photos.app.goo.gl/kig68Kp12mMorUB57

what i have already tested to get those information.

```
//uisng taglib to achieve the result.
TagLib.File file = TagLib.File.Create(FilePath);
string title=file.Tag.Title.ToString();  // its fine and find the related data of the title attribute.
string Tags= file.Tag.Tags.ToString(); // does not return any data and raise error.'does not contain a definition for Tags'.

// using WindowsAPICodePack shell 
 string infos = null;
            foreach (var prop in new ShellPropertyCollection(open.FileName))
            {

                    infos += prop.CanonicalName + "=" + prop.ValueAsObject + "\n";

            }
```

both taglib and (windows api code pack) cant read the field called "Tags" what i am looking for. 
windows api code pack can return name , comment and many others but cant return the "Tags" attribute.

Comment: Your code is essentially the easiest way to do it (windows api code pack). What's wrong?  You've told us 1. what you're trying to accomplish and 2. what you tried, but you haven't told us 3. what was the result and 4. why that doesn't work for you. 3 & 4 are needed to answer questions. You can [edit] to add details.

Comment: @Will the question is updated. and thanks for the replay. please there is an image link the circled aria in image  is what i ma looking to get its data.